# ipywidgets dropdown with pandas MultiIndex

Tags: drop-down-menu, multi-index, ipywidgets

How can the ipywidgets dropdown menu be used with a pandas MultiIndex as the options field?  It seems to display only the first level from the MultiIndex.  For example, the following code run in JupyterLab only shows options [1, 1, 2, 2].

```
import ipywidgets
import pandas as pd

arrays = [[1, 1, 2, 2], ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('number', 'color'))
dropdown = ipywidgets.Dropdown(options=index)
display(dropdown)
```

[image]